# I am having difficulty structuring the following sentence based on the following words

Tags: word-choice, meaning-in-context, american-english

I want to ensure that the following words are conveyed in the sentence:

- Competency
- Cultural-fit
- Inclusion (inside of culture)

My attempt has been the following, but I feel it could be ungrammatical and because of the comma splice, the meaning may not come across as intended.

> Companies will hire for competency, fire for culture fit

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you feel the sentence may be ungrammatical? Are you concerned about the comma splice?

Comment: yes the comma slice, and I am concerned that it may not address all of those three points effectively. My English is weak so i am not sure.

Comment: I edited your post to include that information. Would you kindly edit it also and add a more specific question? Requests for suggestions or feedback aren't topical here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear to me from your question where "inclusion" would fit into this sentence. At the very least, your sentence would benefit from a conjunction, in addition to possible padding of your clauses. (I personally prefer not to use comma splices when communicating new insights. One more obstacle to understanding.)

To the best of my understanding, here would be an alternative structure:

> Companies will hire candidates for competency, and later fire them for failure to fit into work culture.

That seems like a plain way to rephrase your intention. The two phases should be linked by a conjunction, "and." Including a timeline word like "then" further clarifies the cause and effect.

Another version might lean more heavily on industry-specific terms:

> Companies will hire on the basis of competency and fire when cultural-fit fails.

Again, not sure where to put "inclusion." Perhaps an introductory phrase, or a switch to the more mechanical "integration"?

> Since companies expect job candidates to demonstrate 'cultural-fit' in their new positions, they often hire employees on the basis of competency and fire them for failure to integrate into the workplace.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response, and clarification. The industry-specific terms will be use as a slogan, and the more elaborate one as the sub heading. Specificing of the sub heading, this this added details make sense to your suggestions "Since companies expect job candidates to demonstrate cultural fit in their new positions, they often hire employees on the basis of competency and fire them for failure to integrate into the workplace. Our platform understands this reality and addresses it in the following matter:.